# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str with JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Here is my code;

```
f = open("test.json")
data = json.load(f)
loadmain = data['response']['users']
loadurl = loadmain['url']
print loadurl
```

Here is the JSON file

```
{

  "meta": {
"status": 200,
"msg": "OK"
  },

  "response": {
"total_users": 23,
"users": [
  {
    "name": "test",
    "url": "http://testurl.com",
    "updated": 1378151341
  }
...
..
.
```

I am a Python beginner so any feedback on this method appreciated, I am sure the decoding of the URL is not done in the right way. Anyways, my main concern; I want a list of the "url"s from the JSON to display  but I get the "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code example uses an undefined variable `asd`.

Comment: Check the type of `data` and `asd`, either may be a list not a dictionary.

Comment: Whoops, `asd` is meant to be `loadmain` Thank for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to retrieve a list of urls is using a list comprehension:

```
urls = [ user['url'] for user in loadmain ]
```

Comment: This one did it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the problem is in `loadurl = asd['url']`. (apart the unknown `asd`)

In the variable `loadmain` you have a list of arrays, thus you need to do something like:

```
for x in loadmain:
   loadurl = x['url']
```

Comment: That works great! But only loads one (funny enough, the last entry on the JSON file). Will I need a loop for that?

Comment: Well, you'd want to make `loadurl` a list and append to it, otherwise you only get the last URL, but you have the right idea.